# Go to close quote/bracket when I press tab in Vim

Tags: vim

I've been playing with Vim plugins that auto-close quotes and brackets.

I don't think I'll continue using these plugins because they freak me out sometimes with their behaviours, but I thought it would be a nice plugin idea.

Basically the following. When you are inside a block (of quotes or brackets or whatever) pressing tab brings you to the outside, end of the block.

Here's an example, `|` is the cursor:

```
(let stuff (+ 1 2|)) ; yo!

; press tab:
(let stuff (+ 1 2)|) ; yo!

; press tab again:
(let stuff (+ 1 2))| ; yo!
```

Hope that gets the idea across. There probably already is a plugin or config for this somewhere but I would still be interested in seeing how to achieve this.

Quote from a comment of mine, below:

> What I need is something that works in insert mode and ONLY if I'm inside one of these blocks, otherwise do something like inserting a real tab (because how often do you need to put a tab in a string?).

Comment: What have you tried? Are you willing / capable to implement this yourself? Just asking for an implementation or existing plugin doesn't fit this site very well.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I have not tried much TBH. But I am not able enough to do this myself yet (at least not without spending some hours).

Comment: Since you are using lisp you may want to look at [vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people) as well as [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can indeed be implemented with an `:inoremap <expr> <Tab> ...`, which would have to return the (e.g. `<Right>`) keys to move the cursor beyond the closing bracket (an expression mapping is better than temporarily leaving insert mode, which would create a new undo point etc.)

To implement this, you can use `search()` with the `n` flag so it doesn't move, using a regular expression with `\%#` to assert parentheses around the cursor.

```
:inoremap <expr> <Tab> search('\%#[]>)}]', 'n') ? '<Right>' : '<Tab>'
```

Comment: Works quite well. Sorry for the delay, haven't had any time to test thoroughly until today. :)

Comment: Is it possible to add support for quotes? I tried adding `"` in the regex but doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @rendon: `search('\%#[]>)}''"]', 'n')` should do, be aware that quotes are not asymmetic like the other characters, so you don't necessarily move _out_ of a quote.

Answer (score 6):

This will work for one of your requirement but it won't insert `tab` if you are not inside a block.

```
imap <tab> <esc>])a
```

Use the `])` command to move to the end of parenthesis, it will take you to the closing parenthesis.

And you can map it to `tab` with

```
nnoremap <tab> ])
```

Comment: Thanks! What I need is something that works in insert mode and ONLY if I'm inside one of these blocks, otherwise do something like inserting a real tab (because how often do you need to put a tab in a string?).

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that you needed something to work in Insert mode

Comment: Your solution is quite nice. Ingo's is nearer to what I'm asking so I'm going to use his combined with yours. :)

Comment: @Greduan - His solutions are always nice and there's always a lot to learn from them :)